# Was bedeutet "drauf" in diesem Zusammenhang?

Tags: meaning

> Wirtschaftlich betrachtet „zahlen“ sie redensartlich „drauf“, ist der
>   Verkauf nicht gewinnbringend

Dieser Satz sagt vermutlich, dass die Tatsache, dass die Käufer für ein E-Auto zahlen, nicht gewinnbringend für den Konzern ist. Aber ich kann nicht verstehen, was "drauf" in dieser Zusammenhang bedeutet. Kann jemand es erläutern?

Quelle: http://www.dw.com/de/e-autos-in-deutschland/a-18492021

Comment: Das ganze Verb heißt [*draufzahlen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/draufzahlen).

Comment: Ah so basically English draufzahlen must be "paying on top of that" so basically paying extra. Vielen Dank!

Comment: exactly! "drauf" is "on top", both literally and figuratively.

Comment: @Stephie: Why don't you provide this as an answer so we can mark this solved? :)

Comment: @Klaster - too busy for a full answer :-)

Comment: Nitcht die Tatsache dass sie zahlen, sondern nur die Höhe der Zahlung, die eben zu gering ist, vereitelt den Gewinn. Würden die Kunden gar nicht zahlen wäre es natürlich noch ärger.

Comment: Das "redensartlich" ist übrigens vollkommen fehl am Platze - eine andere Verwendung von draufzahlen ist gar nicht im Umlauf - und die Anführungsstriche sind auch Kokolores.

Answer (score 3):

Das ganze Verb heißt

> draufzahlen

Es ist ein teilbares Verb, zerfällt also bei einigen Konjugationen in zwei Teile, die im Satz voneinander getrennt anzutreffen sind:

> Heinz musste noch eine Menge **draufzahlen**.
>   Heinz **zahlte** noch eine Menge **drauf**.

Die beiden Bestandteile bedeuten:

- **zahlen**: Geld ausgeben um dafür eine Ware oder Dienstleistung zu erhalten.
- **drauf**: Umgangssprachliche Kurzform von »*darauf*«. Die Langform *darauf* wird im Zusammenhang mit *zahlen* aber nie verwendet und ist auch sonst eher selten in Verwendung. Das Wort bedeutet: *zusätzlich*. Man legt zu dem, was man normalerweise zahlen müsste, noch etwas oben drauf.

Somit lautet die ursprüngliche Bedeutung von *draufzahlen*: Mehr zahlen als eigentlich vorgesehen war.

Viel häufiger (fast immer) meint man aber: *Einen Nachteil erleiden.* Das kann natürlich der Fall sein, wenn man etwas kauft, das seinen Preis nicht wert ist, muss aber gar nichts mit Kaufen zu tun haben.

Wenn zwei Personen sich streiten, und eine dritte Person kommt hinzu um den Streit zu schlichten, und wenn dieser Streitschlichter dann selbst verprügelt wird, dann zahlt er drauf:

> »Bitte bleibe hier und mische dich nicht ein! Wenn du versuchst, diesen Streit zu schlichten, wirst du nur *draufzahlen*.

In dem zitierten Beispielsatz zahlt der Verkäufer (bzw. der Autohersteller) drauf weil er einen Nachteil erleidet. Die Kunden sind nicht bereit, die tatsächlichen Kosten zu bezahlen, daher verkaufen die Hersteller ihre Elektroautos zu einem Preis, der unter ihren Herstellungskosten liegt. Dadurch erleiden Sie einen Nachteil.

Sieht man den (Ver)kauf mal umgekehrt (Der Händler kauft Geld vom Kunden und bezahlt dafür mit einem Auto), so trifft hier auch die ursprüngliche Bedeutung zu: Der Händler bezahlt für die gekaufte Geldmenge mit einem zu wertvollen Auto.

Comment: Mag kleinlich erscheinen, aber nicht die Händler, sondern die Autokonzerne zahlen drauf, und die Zahlungen sind nicht das zu wertvolle Auto, sondern Löhne, Rohstoffe, Halbfertigprodukte usw.